# me manda error al enviar correo c#

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-forms, .net

que tal tengo un problema el cual
estaba haciendo pruebas con un codigo el cual me permite enviar correos probe el envio por medio de outlook y me sirvio pero cuando lo intento hacer con el dominio de una pagina que tengo este me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces mi codigo es el siguiente (le quite el password)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
namespace AmazonSESSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string filename = @"C:\ruta\img.png";
            Attachment data = new Attachment(filename);

            MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
            correo.From = new MailAddress("robertomendoza@cmg.mx", "desarrollador", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);//Correo de salida
            correo.To.Add("correo@hotmail.com"); //Correo destino?
            correo.Subject = "Correo de prueba"; //Asunto
            correo.Body = "Este es un correo de prueba desde c#"; //Mensaje del correo
            correo.Attachments.Add(data);

            correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
            correo.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Host = "mail.nuestrosite.com"; //Host del servidor de correo
            smtp.Port = 25; //Puerto de salida
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo@cmg.mx", "password");//Cuenta de correo
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;//True si el servidor de correo permite ssl
            smtp.Send(correo);

        }
    }
    }
```

quiero poder enviar el correo por un ejecutable y este a su vez mande el archivo con Cc a mas usuarios pero quiero corregir el error primero

Comment: El error que te está dando es un error de autenticación del cliente (5.7.1). Por cierto, deberías editar tu pregunta y omitir todos los datos personales (las cuentas de correo)

Comment: Intenta en `NetworkCredentials` añadir el dominio, con el formato `new NetworkCredential("usuario", "contraseña", "dominio")`

Comment: me sige mandando el mismo error

Comment: el usuario veo que lo estas poniendo con `@cmg.mx`. Intenta sin el tambien. Si no es eso, no puedo decirte mucho mas la verdad :)